# Function for searching repeated character

Tags: function

How do I write a python function where the code takes string as an argument and searches the repeated characters (expect spaces) then RETURN a dictionary where the keys are the characters and values are the position of the characters

Answer (score 0):

You can use the collections.Counter class:

```
your_string = "abcab"

from collections import Counter

dic = dict(Counter(your_string))
dic
```

Should return a dictionary like this:

{'a': 2, 'b': 2, 'c': 1}